# In Symfony, how to show and submit part of a form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have form type that contains multiple fields. One field is a custom form type that itself contains multiple fields as well. I cannot change the child type because it is in use elsewhere.

I only want to show the fields that are currently not empty but I haven't found a way to do so. I tried hiding them on the twig template - as in, not rendering them if the value is not empty - but then they get submitted as empty so previously set values are now unset.

How can I effectively use part of a Form Type?

*Editing for clarification:*

Say I have a class `OrderType` with the fields `orderNumber` and `identifiers`. The identifiers is a `ItentifiersType` and contains the fields `invoiceNumber`, `name`, `purchaseDate` and `serialNumber`.

The page I'm trying to create should only show the missing data. If the values for `orderNumber` and `purchaseDate` are already present in the database, I only want to show the input fields for `invoiceNumber` and `serialNumber`.

```
$builder->add('identifiers', 'collection', [
    'type' => new IdentifierType(),
    'allow_add' => true
])->add('orderNumber', 'int');
```

Comment: I'm not really following you. Could you add some examples?

Comment: Edited in an example

Comment: add the related code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem. It was kind of awkward to reach the fields inside the `identifiers` field but it works and form handling works as expected.

```
    /* Removed non-empty fields from the form */
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $identifiers = $form->get('identifiers');
            foreach ($identifiers->all()[0]->all() as $identifier) {
                if ($identifier->getData() != null) {
                    $identifiers->all()[0]->remove($identifier->getName());
                }
            }
    });
```